# Is there a reason this React prop function is wrapped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

If you look at the React tic-tac-toe tutorial , you find that when the `Square` is changed from a [Component into a Function](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#function-components), the author removes the arrow function wrapper around the property:

> Note
>
> When we modified the Square to be a function component, we also changed `onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}` to a shorter
> `onClick={props.onClick}` (note the lack of parentheses on both sides).

Was the arrow function wrapping necessary in the first place? It doesn't seem like a closure is necessary to capture the `this`.

---

Edit:

The answer is that the component does not need a wrapping any more than the function version of it does so, but both answers give good reasons why wrap the function call. I accepted this one because it arrived first.

Comment: either you need to bind it in the constructor, or use an arrow function.

Comment: Nope, not at all.

Comment: I tried the component without the wrapping, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: `onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}` allows you to pass custom parameters like `onClick={() => this.props.onClick(1)}`. But without wrapping, it will pass the click event object to that function.

Comment: @HaoWu You can create a curried callback to pass custom arguments, i.e. `const onClick = customArg => event => {...}` and set as callback `onClick={props.onClick(1)}`. This encloses the custom arg in an instance of the callback and it will then still receive the event object, if it needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still uses an arrow function.

It just uses it when the function is passed **to** the `onClick` prop of the `Square` component. (The part of the code you are looking it is reading it **from** that prop).

> ```
>   <Square
>     value={this.state.squares[i]}
>     onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
>   />
> ```

It has to do *something* to bind the `this` value to the component because that function uses `this` internally.

Answer (score 1):

One key difference between wrapping/not wrapping the function is in the arguments forwarding

Usually, the `onClick` callback take the event object as first argument:

```
onClick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.target 
  ...etc...
}
```

Let's compare the two options considering the presence of the argument:

```
onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
```

Here you create a function without arguments, so the `e` event is ignored, and `this.props.onClick()` is called without any argument.

```
onClick={props.onClick}
```

Here you are not creating any 'middleware': `props.onClick` will receive the event as first argument.

This difference is usually meaningless, but it may create some problems if your `props.onClick` object actually has a first argument, especially if it has a default. Assume your final onClick handler is something like that:

```
const exampleOnClick = (firstArgument = false) => {
}
```

```
onClick={() => this.props.onClick()} // You are not passing any argument, so the default will be used

onClick={props.onClick} // Here firstArgument will be the event object, and you may not be expecting that
```

**Note**: It's perfectly fine to NOT wrap the function and it should be a little bit more efficient (you are not creating an additional function for every component at every render). Just consider and be aware of the difference